# Kibana4 not showing any results

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, kibana-4

I have created a Kibana 4 dashboard a few days earlier and named it as "test dashboard".But when I load it now , it is empty as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

It was perfectly working and was showing various analytics when I created. Any clues?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default kibana tries to show the last 15 minutes worth data.
You might not have indexed the any data before that 15 minutes.
In this case , you can change the time filter as shown below -

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have you indexed any data in the last 15 minutes? If not, you need to adjust the time range in the upper right to include a period that has data.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I'd add to Vineeth's answer is that you access the time scales by clicking on the time scale shown in the top right corner of the Kibana screen (in this case 'last 15 minutes')